# AchartEngine Barchart Spacing not working when orientation is vertical and number of elements are 2

Tags: android, achartengine

I am having a AchartEngine Barchart. I have only two bars to show with Orientation as Vertical. The space between the two bars is very high and I am not able to change it. I have tried the following
1. Change the values passed to  setBarSpacing() method from -100, -10, -.9, -.5, -.1,  0, .1, .5, .9, 10, 100
2. Used two XYSeries and then one. In both cases, the space is significant
3. Increased and decreased width of Bar
4. Set the min, max and values at different ranges. min = .9, max = 2.1, x1 = 1, x2 = 2
Nothing is working. Can some one please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method.

The method below adds a barchart showing data for two months with values. If you want to change the color and some other properties, you are free to do that.

```
private void createChart() {
    String[] mMonth = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb" };
    int[] mData = new int[] { 20, 25 };

    // creating XY series for Data
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Performance");

    // fill the data
    for (int i = 0; i < mMonth.length; i++) {
        series.add(i, mData[i]);
    }

    // create a dataset to hold each data series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding dataseries to datast
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    // create a renderer to customize the series
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setLineWidth(2);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30);

    // create a renderer to customize entire chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

    mRenderer.setXTitle("Quarter 1");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Values in K");
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);

    // margins
    int marginT = 50;
    int marginL = 80;
    int marginB = 15;
    int marginR = 15;

    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { marginT, marginL, marginB, marginR });
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    // mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30);
    // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(8, "OT");
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(3);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(2);

    // We want to avoid black border
    // transparent margins
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));

    for (int i = 0; i < mMonth.length; i++) {
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
    }

    // adding renderer to multiple renderer(chart)
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    GraphicalView view = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, dataset,
            mRenderer, Type.STACKED);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlBarChart);
    layout.addView(view, 0);
}
```

Hope this helps.